# How to set timer duration in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timer

I have some problems with my timer. When changing the timer duration, I can't make the timer start from the new duration. How can I fix that? Please help. Here is my code:

CSS:

```
div {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='session'>2</div>
<div id='increase' onclick='decrease()'>-</div>
<div id='increase' onclick='increase()'>+</div>
<div class='session' id='session' onclick='setInterval(changeSessionDuration,100)'>2</div>
```

JS:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('session');
var seconds = 60;

function increase() {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].innerHTML++;
    }
}

function decrease() {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].innerHTML > 0) {
            x[i].innerHTML--;
        }
    }
}

var session = x[1].innerHTML - 1;

function changeSessionDuration() {
    if (seconds > 0) {
        seconds--;
        if (seconds == 0 && session > 0) {
            session--;
            seconds = 60;
        }
    }
    x[1].innerHTML = session + ':' + seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, your timer doesn't start at the correct time that you have added beforehand the timer was running?

If then, it's because of this line:

```
var session = x[1].innerHTML - 1;
```

The value of session is already set before you incremented/decremented the time.

You should set the value of session after the increments/decrements or before starting the run like:

```
<div class='session' id='session' onclick='setSession(); setInterval(changeSessionDuration,100);'>2</div>
```

and the JS would be:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('session');
var seconds = 60;

function increase() {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].innerHTML++;
    }
}

function decrease() {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].innerHTML > 0) {
            x[i].innerHTML--;
        }
    }
}

var session;
function setSession(){
    session = x[1].innerHTML - 1;
}

function changeSessionDuration() {
    if (seconds > 0) {
        seconds--;
        if (seconds == 0 && session > 0) {
            session--;
            seconds = 60;
        }
    }
    x[1].innerHTML = session + ':' + seconds;
}
```

And my example codes are dirty, you should suit it to your flavor.

Comment: Thank you man! You are genious! :D That is  what I exactly want!

Comment: No problem! And i'm not certainly a genious or genius :D

Comment: Let it be genius! :D

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you don't clear previously set interval. You need to create interval within javascript click event listener. Code below is working if you use just one place to print out seconds

```
var x=document.getElementsByClassName('session'),
    interval;

x[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(interval){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  interval = setInterval(changeSessionDuration,100)
}, false); 

var seconds=60;

function increase(){
  for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].innerHTML++;
  }
}

function decrease(){
  for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    if(x[i].innerHTML>0){
        x[i].innerHTML--;
    }
  }
}

var session=x[0].innerHTML-1;

function changeSessionDuration(){
  if (seconds>0){
   seconds--;
  if(seconds==0 && session>0){
     session--;
     seconds=60;
  }
}
 x[0].innerHTML=session +':'+seconds;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but your code doesn't help.It's all the same.

Comment: No it's not? See the second code block, with clearInterval()